# Crystal Report Is Displaying only one row from datatable which has 10 rows

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, report

I have developed a Windows Application which generates report without database using C#.

I have added a Dataset and a DataTable to it as datasource to crystal report. My datatable gets a minimum of 1 row. Even when my datatable has multiple(like 4,5,10) rows the crystal report still displays only the first row of the datatable.

I have used breakpoints and validated that my datatable has multiple rows.

I am using
Windows XP Service Pack 3 (64-Bit) OS
Visual Studio 2010 Professional
.Net Framework 4
Crystal Report(Downloaded From SAP Website last month)

**Thank You**

Please help me out with this

Comment: Post a screenshot of your report in design mode.

Comment: I have uploaded the screenshot here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/201/reportay.jpg/

Comment: Also the Report design screen shot is also uploaded here http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/26/reportdesign.jpg/

Comment: The design appears to be OK.  How many pages are generated?

Comment: only one page is generated.....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you put the table fields in the "Page header" or in the "Report header" section of your report.

If this is the case, you should put your fields in the "Details" section.
The "Detail" section of the report will be repeated for each rows in your data source.

Comment: I have column's(Name, Company, Designation, Place, Distance) in Datatable. I have added only Name & Designation in Report Header, rest all in Details section, The name & Designation appears perfectly, but the rows in details section is not displayed except the first row on datatable

Comment: your report seem fine from what I can see. Maybe there is some grouping/filtering/Max/Min going on somewhere? (in the query? in the datatable/dataview filter? on the internal report filtering/grouping properties?)

Comment: i have checked even that. There us no grouping at all. And there is only one datatable. I think there is a silly mistakewhich i am unable to figure out.

Comment: maybe there is some strange relation (with some lookup table in the report) that is limiting the output? have you tried deleting the first row from the table? what happens? does the 2nd row show up? or then the report is empty?

Comment: But there is no relation used, Deleting!! Where should i try deleting(In datatable)

Comment: you can delete a datarow in the datatable in your SW just before setting the datatable as the datasource of the report